# Limit of Natural Isomorphisms of Factors of a Diagram

Tags: category-theory, profinite-groups

Diagrams $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ are objects of the functor category $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$, when $\mathcal{C}$ is small. A particular case of a small category is the category associated to a directed poset $\Lambda$, where there exists a morphism $f:\beta\to\alpha$ if and only if $\alpha\leq\beta$. Diagrams $F:\Lambda\to\mathcal{D}$ are then objects of $\mathcal{D}^\Lambda$, which send some $\lambda\in\Lambda$ to some $D_\lambda$ in $\mathcal{D}$. The category $\mathcal{D}^\Lambda$ has natural transformations as morphisms, but let's consider natural isomorphisms $\eta:F\Rightarrow F$. Such a natural isomorphism $\eta$ consists of component isomorphisms $\eta_\lambda:D_\lambda\to D_\lambda$ such that for $\alpha\leq\beta$ and $f:\beta\to\alpha$ in $\Lambda$ we have $\eta_\alpha\circ F(f)=F(f)\circ\eta_\beta$.

I believe this corresponds to the case of an inverse system in $\mathcal{D}$: Indeed we have objects $D_\lambda$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$ and we have transition maps $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}:=F(f):D_\beta\to D_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\leq \beta$ in $\Lambda$. The inverse limit of this system is the limit of the diagram $\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}D_\lambda$.

Is there a sense in which there is a corresponding limit $\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\eta_\lambda:\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}D_\lambda\to\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}D_\lambda$? How is this constructed? I am interested in this because automorphisms of $\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}D_\lambda$ could be pretty pathological, swapping isomorphic factors of the diagram, etc. Considering natural isomorphisms of the factors would help me sort out a problem with the semidisjoint union in profinite quandle-land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}$You seem to be discovering the fact that *(co)limits are functors*. In a suitable context. We don't need to reduce to automorphisms or posets, this is quite general.

Suppose $F,G\in\D^\C$ are two diagrams whose limits exist, and suppose $\eta:F\implies G$ is a natural transformation. I claim there is a canonical arrow associated to $\eta$, which we call $\varprojlim\eta$, from $\varprojlim F$ to $\varprojlim G$. When $\D$ admits all limits of shape $\C$, this assignment $\eta\mapsto\varprojlim\eta$ makes $\varprojlim:\D^\C\to\D$ a genuine functor.

To get an arrow $\varprojlim F\to\varprojlim G$ is to specify a cone over $G$ with apex $\varprojlim F$. We define the legs of this cone, for $c\in\C$, to be: $$\varprojlim F\to F(c)\overset{\eta_c}{\longrightarrow}G(c)$$Where the first arrow is the leg of the limit cone. Exercise: use naturality of $\eta$ to show that this really does define a cone $\varprojlim F\implies G$.

The universal property of a limit induces from this cone a well-defined arrow $\varprojlim\eta:\varprojlim F\to\varprojlim G$.

Comment: Ohhh, a every functor has a component-function $F:\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\to\text{Ob}(\mathcal{D})$ and a component-function $F:\text{Mor}(\mathcal{C})\to\text{Mor}(\mathcal{D})$. So then if $\varprojlim$ is a functor taking objects of $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$, aka diagrams, to objects of $\mathcal{D}$, then it also will take the morphisms of $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ to morphisms of $\mathcal{D}$. Morphisms in $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ are natural transformations, so it associates a morphism $\varprojlim\eta$ of $\mathcal{D}$ to each natural transformation $\eta$ in $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: In my context, then, my $\varprojlim\eta$ in $\mathcal{D}$ is an isomorphism between the object $\varprojlim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}D_\lambda$ and itself, so an automorphism, and I can check that it behaves as a special type of automorphism, i.e., one which can't do annoying things such as permute factors of the diagram?

Comment: @AlexByard Your first comment is confusing me. The whole point of this answer is to describe how we take natural transformations to their "limit" arrow in $\mathcal{D}$. I don't know what you mean by permuting the factors, but this $\varprojlim\eta$ arrow has quite an explicit description which you can inspect

Comment: Okay, I'm using this to deal with diagrams of profinite quandles. Semidisjoint unions are defined by taking two quandles and having them act on each other through the other's automorphism group, which is where I'm having issues. I think that having them act through the $\varprojlim\eta$ will work better. But ignore that, does the comment where I roughly tried to follow the lines of the argument make sense, i.e., $\varprojlim$ being a functor which assigns not only sends diagrams to objects of $\mathcal{D}$ but sends natural transformations to their limit morphisms also?

Comment: @AlexByard That's part of what it means to be a functor and that's what I meant when I said, through $\eta\mapsto\varprojlim\eta$, $\varprojlim$ becomes a functor (if all the limits exist)

Comment: Ah, so you have described a procedure through which you find a canonical arrow in $\mathcal{D}$ associated to $\eta$, and this makes $\varprojlim$ a functor.  I understand now why $\varprojlim$ is a functor, through your construction, and this was exactly what I was trying to discover. Thank you : ) I'll accept the answer

Comment: @AlexByard Right. Also colimit is a functor if all the colimits exist, and $\varinjlim\eta$ is formed through a very similar construction

Comment: I don't know much about colimits. I started looking into limits as the inverse limit of inverse systems so I could work with profinite things. Now I'm trying to expand my categorical knowledge. Colimits give rise to ind-objects, right? I've heard of that before but I haven't looked into them a lot.

Comment: @AlexByard "Ind-objects" sounds like some archaic term from abstract algebra, but I have no idea what you mean. Colimits are just completely dual to limits. The colimit of a functor $F:C\to D$ is the limit of $F^{op}:C^{op}\to D^{op}$

Comment: Oh I see, so you just reverse all the arrows in your cone? I saw indfinite in a quandle paper as a dual to profinite, so I assumed the term ind-object is the dual to pro-object, but idk if anyone uses that terminology anymore.

Comment: @AlexByard "... you just reverse ..." - pretty much. A colimit for a functor $F:C\to D$ is a **co**cone: an object $X$ and a family $\lambda_c:F(c)\to X$ of arrows, $c\in C$, with the property that if $f:c\to c'$ is an arrow in $C$ then $\lambda_{c'}\circ F(f)=\lambda_c$; which is a *universal* cocone (any other cocone "under" $F$, any such $(\mu_c:F(c)\to Y)$, has a unique arrow $\alpha:X\to Y$ satisfying $\alpha\circ\lambda_c=\mu_c$ for all $c\in C$)

Comment: This is the same as the definition of a limit except almost all the arrows are reversed

Comment: Ah okay. Do colimits come with a lot of the same properties as limits or is it different almost entirely? One of the most interesting things I read about in category theory is the profinite/Stone-topological equivalence for certain finitary algebraic categories $\mathcal{A}$, which demonstrates that any such Stone topological $\mathcal{A}$-algebra is homeomorphic to a limit of a diagram in that category. I guess a lot of that rides on the particular finitary algebraic category you choose, but are there similar connections to be made with "indfinite" things as colimits of diagrams?

Comment: Admittedly that question is really specific, but what is nice about colimits in general?

Comment: Uh, colimits just appear around the place. They're as useful a construction as limits since they literally are just the dual construction, and duality goes both ways.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look. I'm not too verbose in category theoretic language, but you explained everything well. Maybe I'll make a new post looking for an answer to the question about Stone topologies.

Comment: @FShrike FYI, "Ind-object" is not at archaic term from abstract algebra. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object).